# Avoid getting the output of sapply() in R Markdown

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, sapply

I made a function systemFail(x), where x is one of the columns in my data frame (df$location).

Now I want to create a new column in my data frame (df$outcome) with the result of this function (Pass/Fail result). I used the line of code below which made the extra column as I wanted. However, annoyingly the result (a long column of Passes and Fails) also shows up in my R Markdown document.

How can I get the extra column in my data frame without getting the result also in my R Markdown document?

```
df$outcome <- sapply(df$location, systemFail)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without knowing details of `systemFail` function. However, from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146741/function-with-a-nested-loop-in-r) it seems you are printing the values in the function. Instead of printing use `return` to return the result.

Look at this simple example -

```
systemFail <- function(x) {
  print(x)
}
res <- systemFail('out')
#[1] "out"
```

and when we use `return` nothing is printed and the result is available in `res`.

```
systemFail <- function(x) {
  return(x)
}
res <- systemFail('out')
```